# Volume of Solid of revolution of some body in a ball

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the Volume of Solid of revolution of $D$,which is subset of the ball $\{x^2+y^2+(z-\frac{1}{2})^2\le(\frac{1}{2})^2\}$ and is above the cone $\{z=\surd(x^2+y^2)\}$.

My question - I'm not sure, how can I find which substitution should I do/use here? How can I find which is the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solid of revolution, or just the volume of the solid?

Spherical coordinates:

$\iiint dz\ dy\ dx  = \iiint \rho^2\sin\phi\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

limits

$x = \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\\y = \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\z = \rho\cos\phi$

$x^2+ y^2 + z^2-z = 0\\
\rho^2= \rho\cos\phi\\
\rho = 0, \rho = \cos \phi$

$z=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
\rho\cos\phi = |\rho\sin\phi|\\
\tan\phi = 1\\
\phi = \frac {\pi}4\\
$

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac {\pi}4} \int_0^{\cos\phi} \rho^2\sin\phi\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = z$  Substitute: $\rho^2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\cos^2\phi = \rho\cos\phi$ Simplify: $\rho^2 = \rho\cos\phi$

Answer (score 3):

You need to project the solid in the $xy$ plane and use cylindrical coordinates. The sphere and the cone intersect when
$$
r^2+(r-\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad r \in \{0,\frac{1}{2}\}
$$

So the projection in the $xy$ plane is the domain
$$
D=\{(r,\theta)\; |\; 0 \le r \le \frac{1}{2}, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi \}
$$

It follows that the volume equals
$$
V = \iint_D \left((\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-r^2})-r\right )\; rdrd\theta
$$